# Getting Agenda Font to work in IE9 with @font-face kit... font-squirrel says the font bureau has disallowed it

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9, font-face

OK so I am trying to get IE9 to display the font Agenda. I went to fontsquirrel like usual and it says that font bureau doesn't allow them to create the font kit. I then went to codeandmore and made the kit there but they do not GIVE YOU EXPERT OPTIONS TO MAKE A LITE VERSION OF THE FONT. In IE 9, I get error CSS3111 and CSS3114:

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
agenda-light.eot?#iefix
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable. 
agenda-light.ttf
```

I have tried multiple work arounds such as making the font face target the woff specifically which did not work.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'IE9Agenda-Light';
        src: url('agenda-light.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
```

I have added an .htaccess file with this syntax:

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
```

I think I need to place some kind of config file here but not sure what to use: ALSO MY CLIENT PURCHASED THE FONT so I don't have an illegal font. Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Agenda-Bold';
        src: url('agenda-bold.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url('agenda-bold.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('agenda-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('agenda-bold.svg#agenda-bold') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
        font-family: 'Agenda-Light';
        src: url('agenda-light.eot');
        src: url('agenda-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url('agenda-light.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('agenda-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('agenda-light.svg#agenda-light') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
}
```

THIS WORKS IN EVERY BROWSER EXCEPT FOR IE9, If someone has an alternative font face generator to font squirrel that will pack up the eot file as a lite version instead of the eot.compressed version that would be helpful that seems to be the only work around I have not found yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Agenda font is available for web font use only as a hosted service, according to http://www.fontbureau.com/webfonts/ and this means that you should use the code provided to refer to the service, instead of generating your own font files.

If the font was purchased under a normal (non-web-font) license, you are not allowed to use it as a web font. See http://www.webtype.com/info/articles/fonts-and-the-law/